# why ssh-copy-id still need password when using fabric

Tags: ssh, fabric

I have set env.user and env.password,but when I use:

```
run('ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub server1')
```

it still asks me for the password,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env.user` and `env.password` are used to ssh to remote server and then run the command inside `run ()` at the remote server.

They are not used for the remote command itself (running in the remote server).

So `ssh-copy-id` doesn't know anything about the user or password.

If this is not what you mean, I would advice you to edit the question and make things more clear, like providing more context of what you are trying to accomplish: pasting the function that contains this 'run' for example.